# How to validate a field value at activeRecord model in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

is there something like:

```
validates_value_of :verified,:with=>1
```

to validate the boolean field on the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to always be true, use [validates_acceptance_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_acceptance_of). If you want it be either true or false, use [validates_inclusion_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/HelperMethods.html#method-i-validates_inclusion_of).

```
validates_acceptance_of :verified
validates_inclusion_of :verified, :in => [ true, false ]
```

Answer (score 2):

See [validates_inclusion_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_inclusion_of):

```
validates_inclusion_of :verified, :in => [1]
```

in your case